# nodejs res.end(data) is not served on certain facebook webviews

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, cookies

I have nodejs based news website. I have added logs on before and after res.end(data) and serving a plain html file to user. part of html data i am serving, i m loading a hidden image (tried in head and body both) and logging the loading of hidden image.

Now my problem is that i see there are lot of request coming with refer m.facebook.com which shows logs of nodejs serving to request but hidden image loading is not getting logged (not called).

Things I have tried :

To Eliminate that these request might be facebook crawler, i have added a cookie on client side, and i can see that cookie is coming in the requests which are not loading hidden image.

The url to page sample is [http://specialcoveragenews.in/news/politics-news/navjot-singh-sidhu-join-in-aap-on-15-august-and-will-campaign-for-the-party-28799](http://news%20link)

The res code is :

```
    profileLogger.logDetails(req,"static-callingRender",{"url":req.pathname,"user agent":req.headers["user-agent"],"requestId":req.environment.requestId,"isBot":isBot,"ip":ip,"isold":isOldUser,"referer":referer});
    var renderUrl = "partners/"+req.partner+"/"+props.template;
    res.render(renderUrl, {
          data : dataV

        }, function(err, html) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error('in index file', err.message);
                return next(err);
            }
            profileLogger.logDetails(req,"static-rendering",{"url":req.pathname,"user agent":req.headers["user-agent"],"requestId":req.environment.requestId,"isBot":isBot,"ip":ip,"isold":isOldUser,"referer":referer});
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(html);
            profileLogger.logDetails(req,"static-complete-rendering",{"url":req.pathname,"user agent":req.headers["user-agent"],"requestId":req.environment.requestId,"isBot":isBot,"ip":ip,"isold":isOldUser,"referer":referer});
        });
    return;

}
```

All the logs added on nodejs serving side are coming, but hidden image loading logs are not coming.

This happen only with facebook refering urls m.facebook.com and only for webviews as user agents for these request are like

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-gb; GT-I9060 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/86.0.0.19.69;]

We have been hitting our heads and not able to understand what is wrong as its not problem with all users coming referer as m.facebook.com but specific to some users.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're sending data with `res.end(html)`? The express API recommends you send your actual data with `res.send()` or `res.json()` http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end

Comment: No, we were using res.send only previously and to debug the problem, it might have to do something with res.send so tried with res.end too